# GAE Data nucleus not fetching child entities

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus

I m using JDO version 2 Data nucleus with App engine SDK 1.7.3. I am having problem retrieving child objects in one to many relationship.

```
contents = (Collection<ContentType>) persistenceManager.newQuery(ContentType.class).execute();
```

This query returns all instances of ContentType but ContentType also contains a list of its children "Content" which are not fetched from Database.

**ContentType.java**

```
public Collection<ContentType> getAllContents() {

        PersistenceManager persistenceManager = PersistenceFactory
                .getInstance().getPersistenceManager();
        Transaction transaction = persistenceManager.currentTransaction();
        Collection<ContentType> contents = null;
        try {
            transaction.begin();
            contents = (Collection<ContentType>) persistenceManager.newQuery(ContentType.class).execute();


            Logging.log("contents in getAllContents=== "+ contents);

            if(contents!=null)
                {
                Logging.log("contents size in getAllContents=== "+ contents.size());

                }

        for (ContentType contentTypeElement : contents) {
            Logging.log("inside main loop in getAllContents, contentTypeElement=== "+ contentTypeElement);
            if(contentTypeElement!=null)
            {
                Logging.log("inside main loop in getAllContents, contentTypeElement having list === "+ contentTypeElement.getContentList());

            }
            if(contentTypeElement.getContentList()!=null)
            {

            for (Content contentElement : contentTypeElement.getContentList()) {
                Logging.log("inside second loop in getAllContents");
                String contentPath = Constants.CONTENT_BASE_URL
                        + contentElement.getContentPath();
                contentElement.setContentPath(contentPath);
            }
            }
            Logging.log("At end of main loop iteration");
        }
        transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            transaction.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
            Logging.log("Exception retriving all content, detail in getAllContents: "
                    + e.toString());

        } finally {
            persistenceManager.close();
        }
        return contents;
    }
```

Here is the log

```
2012-12-14 13:27:14.101
org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl internalPreCommit: >> calling preCommit on org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl$2@873b9f
I 2012-12-14 13:27:14.102
org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl internalPreCommit: >> calling preCommit on org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@c6b8b0
I 2012-12-14 13:27:14.102
org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl preFlush: >> calling preFlush on org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl$2@873b9f
I 2012-12-14 13:27:14.102
org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl preFlush: >> calling preFlush on org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@c6b8b0
I 2012-12-14 13:27:14.135
com.test.igreetings.util.Logging log: contents in getAllContents=== [com.test.igreetings.persistence.domain.ContentType@14fdb76, com.test.igreetings.persistence.domain.ContentType@1d15a18, com.test.igreetings.persistence.domain.ContentType@171f735, com.test.igreetings.persistence.domain.ContentType@1bf496b]
I 2012-12-14 13:27:14.135
com.test.igreetings.util.Logging log: contents size in getAllContents=== 4
I 2012-12-14 13:27:14.135
com.test.igreetings.util.Logging log: inside main loop in getAllContents, contentTypeElement=== com.test.igreetings.persistence.domain.ContentType@14fdb76
I 2012-12-14 13:27:14.135
com.test.igreetings.util.Logging log: inside main loop in getAllContents, contentTypeElement having list === null
I 2012-12-14 13:27:14.135
com.test.igreetings.util.Logging log: At end of main loop iteration
I 2012-12-14 13:27:14.135
com.test.igreetings.util.Logging log: inside main loop in getAllContents, contentTypeElement=== com.test.igreetings.persistence.domain.ContentType@1d15a18
I 2012-12-14 13:27:14.135
com.test.igreetings.util.Logging log: inside main loop in getAllContents, contentTypeElement having list === null
I 2012-12-14 13:27:14.135
com.test.igreetings.util.Logging log: At end of main loop iteration
I 2012-12-14 13:27:14.135
com.test.igreetings.util.Logging log: inside main loop in getAllContents, contentTypeElement=== com.test.igreetings.persistence.domain.ContentType@171f735
I 2012-12-14 13:27:14.135
com.test.igreetings.util.Logging log: inside main loop in getAllContents, contentTypeElement having list === null
I 2012-12-14 13:27:14.135
com.test.igreetings.util.Logging log: At end of main loop iteration
I 2012-12-14 13:27:14.135
com.test.igreetings.util.Logging log: inside main loop in getAllContents, contentTypeElement=== com.test.igreetings.persistence.domain.ContentType@1bf496b
I 2012-12-14 13:27:14.135
com.test.igreetings.util.Logging log: inside main loop in getAllContents, contentTypeElement having list === null
I 2012-12-14 13:27:14.135
com.test.igreetings.util.Logging log: At end of main loop iteration
I 2012-12-14 13:27:14.136
org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl internalPreCommit: >> calling preCommit on org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl$2@66da2c
I 2012-12-14 13:27:14.136
org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl internalPreCommit: >> calling preCommit on org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@274608
```

**DATA NUCLEUS LOGS**

```
1.  org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl allocateConnection: Connection added to the pool : com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection@74ece8 for key=org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@107c76b in factory=ConnectionFactory:tx[com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl@119549e]
2.  
3.  D2012-12-14 17:20:11.232
4.  org.datanucleus.store.query.QueryManager getQueryCompilationForQuery: Query "SELECT FROM com.test.igreetings.persistence.domain.ContentType" of language "JDOQL" has been run before so reusing existing generic compilation
5.  D2012-12-14 17:20:11.232
6.  com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.JDOQLQuery performExecute: JDOQL Query : Executing "SELECT FROM com.test.igreetings.persistence.domain.ContentType" ...
7.  D2012-12-14 17:20:11.233
8.  com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.JDOQLQuery performExecute: Query compiled as : Kind=com.test.igreetings.persistence.domain.ContentType
9.  D2012-12-14 17:20:11.233
10. com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.DatastoreQuery executeNormalQuery: Executing query in datastore for SELECT FROM com.test.igreetings.persistence.domain.ContentType
11. D2012-12-14 17:20:11.233
12. org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl allocateConnection: Connection found in the pool : com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection@74ece8 for key=org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@107c76b in factory=ConnectionFactory:tx[com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl@119549e]
13. D2012-12-14 17:20:11.234
14. com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.JDOQLQuery performExecute: JDOQL Query : Execution Time = 2 ms
15. D2012-12-14 17:20:11.279
16. org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl getObjectFromLevel1Cache: Object with id "com.test.igreetings.persistence.domain.ContentType:ContentType(3)" not found in Level 1 cache [cache size = 0]
17. D2012-12-14 17:20:11.279
18. org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl putObjectIntoLevel1Cache: Object "com.test.igreetings.persistence.domain.ContentType@165d118" (id="com.test.igreetings.persistence.domain.ContentType:ContentType(3)") added to Level 1 cache (loadedFlags="[NNYNN]")
19. D2012-12-14 17:20:11.279
20. org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager wrapSCOField: Object "com.test.igreetings.persistence.domain.ContentType@165d118" (id="com.test.igreetings.persistence.domain.ContentType:ContentType(3)") is having the value in field "endDate" replaced by a SCO wrapper
21. D2012-12-14 17:20:11.280
22. org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager wrapSCOField: Object "com.test.igreetings.persistence.domain.ContentType@165d118" (id="com.test.igreetings.persistence.domain.ContentType:ContentType(3)") is having the value in field "startDate" replaced by a SCO wrapper
23. D2012-12-14 17:20:11.280
24. org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl enlistInTransaction: Object "com.test.igreetings.persistence.domain.ContentType@165d118" (id="com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key:ContentType(3)") enlisted in transactional cache
25. D2012-12-14 17:20:11.280
26. org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl getObjectFromLevel2Cache: Object with id="com.test.igreetings.persistence.domain.ContentType:ContentType(3)" taken from Level 2 cache (fields="[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]", version="") - represented as "com.test.igreetings.persistence.domain.ContentType@165d118"
27. D2012-12-14 17:20:11.280
org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl allocateConnection: Connection found in the pool : com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection@74ece8 for key=org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@107c76b in factory=ConnectionFactory:tx[com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl@119549e]
```

So contentList is fetched empty although in admin console Data viewer there are many instances of Content associated with Content Types. What am i missing?

Comment: missing? posting the rest of your code where you check that a collection field is null, and where the transaction is relative to that, what lifecycle states the ContentType objects are in when you check, and what the log says

Comment: @DataNucleus. qusetion edited. code and logs added

Comment: and wheres the rest of the log ? the DataNucleus log. The bit where you invoke a query, and it tells you what its doing

Comment: What is in the datastore for the property for the collection field? What is the rest of the ContentType class ? You can easily compare with all of the tests under http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Ftests%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fappengine%2Fdatanucleus which have collections and load them with no problem

Comment: In the datastore, when i click on the Primary Key of a child record then this is what i get:
Decoded entity key: ContentType: id=3 > Content: id=8
Which means ContentType object(parent) of Id 3 is associated with this content(child) record on its primary key.
How do we tell to java entity that a whole object is associated with your primary Key?

Comment: i'm not referring to the child object. I'm referring to the property in the ContentType that stores its collection element keys.

Comment: This is how Content Class is binded with ContentType:   '@Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
 @Element(dependent = "true")
 private List<Content> contentList;'

Comment: @DataNucleus. let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21144/discussion-between-imran-tariq-and-datanucleus)

Comment: I asked what is that property (for the List) in the datastore.

Comment: There is nothing in data store against that collection property. Its only fields in datastore are: start date, end date, title and primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you now say that there is no property in ContentType for the List then you didn't persist the data with v2 of the GAE JDO plugin. Consequently you can't expect it to know about elements in the Collection.

Solution : fix your data.

Comment: Thanks. I am sure it will work. Is there any link that will help me understand this problem better.

Comment: The only link I can find is http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/wiki/DataMigrationProcess_for_Version2 which describes a way of migrating GAE JDO v1 data across. Alternatively you can do it manually, by adding a property to the owner object and storing a List<Key> with the keys of the elements. Alternatively just persist a new owner+elements and look at what it creates as a guide

Comment: There is one small problem though. When i update/delete the data in the datastore directly through console then my java entities are not updated and i keep getting old state.

Comment: if you delete objects that are in a collection through some other mechanism than JDO then you're taking responsibility to also update the List<Key> field in the owner object.

Comment: The List<Content> is persistent and present in my entity but i do not see anything against it in the datastore(Though this list is fetched correctly in java entity). Is there no way to synchronize my java entities with the latest state of data store?

Comment: The Collection field in a Java object comes from the List<Key> in the associated Entity. That's all there is. The tests for this are all in public SVN, so suggest that you look at them if you think there is some problem (to work out where the problem is in your code)

Comment: "if you delete objects that are in a collection through some other mechanism than JDO then you're taking responsibility to also update the List<Key> field in the owner object" 
Yes i am deleting objects in collection through datstore viewer and not through JDO. How to reflect this deletion in my java entity.

Comment: delete the Key of that deleted object from the "List<Key>" property of any owner objects that reference it

Comment: The "List<Key>" property in owner is not editable in data store viewer.

Comment: Also, this deletion is reflected in java entity only when 2 or 3 JDO retrieval calls are made after manual deletion.